# iOS app crashes on app termination with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on global/static variables

Tags: c++, ios, global-variables

In my iOS application, I'm getting an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** crash on one of the global variables I use in my C/C++ code when the app is terminated. Please note that the app is not put to background but is terminated on closing the app by specifying to not run in background in the info plist file.

Following is the related code..

```
#include "chromium/threading/thread_local.h"
#include "libev/ev.c"

namespace simplegetter {


ThreadLocalPointer<ev_io> threadLocal_sock_watcher;
ThreadLocalPointer<ev_timer> threadLocal_timer;


void start_get (my_get_struct* get_struct) {

    ev_io* sock = new ev_io;
    ev_timer* temp_timer = new ev_timer;

    threadLocal_sock_watcher.Set(sock);
    threadLocal_timer.Set(temp_timer);

    //... other code.. 

}

void fire_again(my_get_struct* get_struct, uint32_t rtt) {
    double repeat = get_client_repeat_value(rtt);
    if (repeat < 0.5) repeat = 0.5;
    threadLocal_timer.Get()->repeat = repeat;
    get_struct->prev_timeout_finish_time = CURRENT_TIME_MS;
    ev_timer_again( threadLocalLoop.Get(), threadLocal_timer.Get());

    //.. other code
}

//... other code 

};
```

**threadLocal_timer** is the **global variable** I'm talking about. the **start_get** method is called on a new thread to fetch a network resource. The **fire_again** method gets called multiple times on the thread that called **start_get** method until the operation is completed.

Now the issue is, on app termination (i.e when iOS sends an exit() call on the main thread.. (which is because the app is not supposed to stay in suspended state or run in background), iOS seem to be releasing off the global variable i.e threadLocal_timer in this case which leads to a crash **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** in my code at line:

```
threadLocal_timer.Get()->repeat = repeat;
```

So, the global variable is **released by the iOS** before the thread is stopped on termination of the app. My question is, is there any solution on how I can deal with this crash apart from not using static or global variables at all in the above code?

Comment: What library, what variables? Sorry, we are no clairvoyants.

Comment: @SergeyA this C/C++ library is an internal library itself that has some static and global variables in the code. ex: ev_timer is one such global variable on which there is a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Comment: No, it is not clear. We have no idea what is happening inside your library.

Comment: @SergeyA seems like I just confused more by mentioning that separate c/c++ code as a library. it's just plain code in the app but we just maintain it separate. Modified my question again to remove the confusion.

Comment: @SergeyA just posted some code and reformatted the question. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I have posted my code as per the suggestions I got. Is there something that is still not clear? I'm not sure if the question is not related - because this is clearly about iOS behaviour and deals with c/c++ code. Can you please let me know on what is not clear or why this would be an off topic question? I'm just asking so that I know the problem and change my question or remove it off based on your feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague.

I have written apps that have long-running background processes that depend on global resources, much like you describe.

What I did was to have a global background task count. Each time I started one of these long-running tasks, I called a function on the main thread that incremented the task count.

At the very end of the shutdown code for the long-running tasks, I call another function (on the main thread) that decrements the counter.)

In the code that decrements the thread count, if the count hits zero, I deallocate and nil out my global resources.

With that logic, the global resources are not freed until the last background thread is done with them.

An approach like that would probably work for your problem but I can't be more specific without knowing more about it.

Comment: I have edited my question and posted relevant code. My problem is iOS releases the global variables that I used before stopping a thread that uses those variables. Please let me know if I'm still unclear. Thanks for bothering to answer.